# Как выглядит код на Ардуино с постепенным включением светодиода только используя digitalWrite

Tags: arduino

Как выглядит код на Ардуино с постепенным включением светодиода только с использованием digitalWrite

Comment: Никак... Если вы хотите постепенно включать, то только Аналог от 0 до 255 повышать.

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример скетча:

```
#define BUTTON 8        // Кнопка на пине 8 (замыкает на землю)
#define FADE   64       // Скорость затухания

bool state = false;     // Состояние светодиода
unsigned char pwm = 0;  // Счётчик ШИМ

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
}

void fade(unsigned char pwm)
{
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); 
  for (unsigned int n = 0; n < pwm * FADE; ++n)
    _NOP();
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  for (unsigned int n = (256 - pwm) * FADE; n > 0; --n)
    _NOP();
}

void loop() 
{
  if (state) {
    // Зажигаем светодиод
    if (pwm < 254) {
      ++pwm;
      fade(pwm);
    }
    else {
      pwm = 255;
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); 
    }
  }
  else {
    // Гасим светодиод
    if (pwm > 1) {
      --pwm;
      fade(pwm);
    }
    else {
      pwm = 0;
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    }
  }
  // Нажатие кнопки включает/выключает светодиод
  bool buttonPressed = false;
  while (digitalRead(BUTTON) == 0) {
    buttonPressed = true;
    delay(100);
  }
  if (buttonPressed)
    state = !state;
}
```

Светодиод - встроенный, кнопка подключена к выводу Digital 8 по схеме "отпущена - плюс, нажата - 0".

При нажатии на кнопку светодиод включается, при следующем нажатии - выключается.

Скорость затухания (интервал перехода из одного состояния в другое) регулируется константой FADE.